# URL rewriting IIS6

Tags: url, seo

Hi i was using HttpModule to Perform Extension-Less URL Rewriting 
as explained at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx Approach 3: 
works perfectly in IIS7, now i just published the solution to the live environment it doesnt work.
the reason seems to be the fact that they are running IIS6
the question is

does anyone now any quick solution to make it work in IIS6 without having to change all the code?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you check out [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/), the Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter. It works with IIS 6 and 7 and supports a directive-and-regex-based syntax similar to Apache's `mod_rewrite`. It's Open Source donationware.